# Bash hangs in Linux subsystem in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Windows 10, I am using Linux subsystem. I first open a cmd terminal with administrator, and then start `bash` in the cmd terminal, and then use the bash shell.

Sometimes my bash hangs upon running in a terminal.

For example, when a file is opened by some software in Windows, I try to rename the parent directory of the file by `mv fileParentDir fileParentDirnew` in bash, and then bash will hang.
If I force to close the bash terminal, and then reopen a new cmd terminal to start `bash` again, the command `bash` will hang too. The problem can be solved by restarting Windows.

is there a solution to the hang problem, not by restarting Windows?

I googled and some said that multiple partition files might be the reason. But I am only using one single partition and partition file.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing when it hangs?

Comment: I don't know. it also happens when inside a bash session running some commands there.

Comment: When a command hangs inside bash, it hangs only when hitting return key to run it, not when I am typing. Can I kill and restart the process which is for running the linux subsystem in Windows?

Comment: For example, some commands for some file operations may hang, especially when they are changing the same file as some process in Windows. How can I kill and restart the processes related to the Linux subsystem? Will that solve the problem?

Comment: For example, I `mv` a file in bash, and the file is also opened by a process in Windows. Most of time it will abort and report error, but sometimes it will hang and not return.

Answer (score 5):

**NOTICE:** *The fix for this bug has now been released publicly.  If you still have the issue, make sure Windows 10 is up-to-date.*

---

This is a known issue, and apparently, you must restart the computer to recover:
[Issue 671 - mv empty subfolder causes deadlock - BashOnWindows GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/671).

The issue was fixed in the Windows Insider Preview Build 14901 back in August.

> [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows - Release Notes (Build 14901)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14901)
>
> First Insider build for the post Windows 10 Anniversary Update
>   release.
>
> For general Windows information on build 14901 visit the Windows Blog.
>   To track or report an issue visit our Github page.
>
> Fixed trailing slash issue Commands such as `$ mv a/c/ a/b/` now work

Solutions:

1. Install any Windows Insider Preview Build 14901 or later
2. Wait for the Anniversary Update to be released for all
3. Avoid command-line arguments ending in a slash.

Comment: Thanks. I am installing a Windows Iniser Preview Build, and it says that my files, apps and settings can’t be kept because I am installing an edition of Windows that’s different than the one I am currently using.
I guess that means that my setups will be removed and I will have to redo everything, correct?
I am weighing between fixing the bash bug vs losing and redoing everything.

Comment: Your assessment seems to be the case.  I have never installed an Insider Build.  That's your call to make.

Comment: @Tim What did you decide to do?

Answer (score 1):

So I was having this issue as well. I am on a domain joined PC and this was part the problem I believe.

When running commands, after pressing "Enter" the shell would hang and it would tell me (sometimes) that it couldn't find my "hostname". I noticed this occurred every time I used sudo or when I would expect DNS to come into play.

I ran these commands:

```
# hostname --short
host    

hostname --domain
[error message]
```

From this I decided to check the hostname file and ensure that my FQDN was set (it wasn't)

```
/etc/hostname
```

Once I set that to host.domain.com, I ran the following:

```
sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

I no longer have any hanging after running commands and no more complaints about unable to find hostnames. I'm not sure if you are on a domain, but if you are, it may be worth checking out.

**NOTE: For some reason, I have to do this every time I open bash. It's really frustrating...**

**ANOTHER NOTE: I find it best to run bash as an administrator. You can't even use ping without doing that.**